# Register the products considering the plan signed by the user - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I'm trying to register products considering the plan that the user signed at the time of registration. I have 3 tables involved in this!

**plans**: id, name, amout, payment_methods

**subscriptions**: id, name, email, user_id, plan_id

I am trying to check what the user plan is in my Products controller. My product table has the related user_id field.

I tried something like:`

```
if ($this->Auth->user('Subscriptions.plan_id') == '510463'){
.
.
.
```

But it didn't work very well. The ideal would be to have the plan_id field in the users table?

I appreciate any comments!

Comment: `$this->Auth->user` is for *authentication* details about the user. That would, at least by default, not include subscriptions. You could add it there with a custom auth finder (specifics of that would depend on whether you're using the old component or the new plugin). If that's not the right approach for you, maybe use `$this->Auth->user('id')` to get the current user ID, then use that to read related records from the subscriptions table? Or if `$this->Auth->user()` gives you the user entity (might or might not, depending on the situation), you could use `loadInfo` to get the subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, my question would really be to verify which plan was signed by the customer in the Products controller. The product table has no relation to subscriptions and plans. I'm trying to check something like: plan = '1234' and count ($ product <= 50) {
// Save  ...

My subscription table has plano_id and user_id

Comment: None of that invalidates what I've suggested, as far as I can tell.